# How to change a children type using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, video.js

I am using Video.js and I want to play both YouTube and mp4 videos. I have the following code for my player

```
<video id="my-video" class="video-js vjs-big-play-centered" data-setup='{ "controls": true, "autoplay": true, "preload": "auto" }' width="1250" height="900" poster="" data-setup='{" techOrder ": ["youtube "]}'>
<source src="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_Z_Se7eJNiM" type='video/youtube'>
<p class="vjs-no-js">
  To view this video please enable JavaScript, and consider upgrading to a web browser that
  <a href="http://videojs.com/html5-video-support/" target="_blank">supports HTML5 video</a>
</p>
```

Here is the code used to change the source whenever a link with the id (source_one) is clicked:

```
  var a = document.getElementById('source_one');

  a.addEventListener('click', function() {
        document.getElementById("my-video").children[0].src = "http://example.com/video.mp4";
  })
```

The Problem is that i cannot find a way to change the source type to `video/mp4`, using `src` changes the source of the video but does not change the `type`.

Comment: where do `source_one` come from

Comment: `<a href="#" class="list-group-item" id="source_one">test</a>`

From a link

Answer (score 1):

I just found out the Solution! Thanks for the answers so far.

```
 var a = document.getElementById('source_one');
    a.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var player = window.player = videojs('my-video');

        var vidlink = $(this).attr('href');

        player.src({
            src: 'http://example.com/test.mp4',
            type: 'video/mp4'
        });
    })
```

Comment: could you explain the solution a little and maybe mark yourself as having answered it to help others in future?

Answer (score 0):

You could try this

```
document.getElementById("my-video").children[0].setAttribute("type", "video/mp4");
```

Comment: Have you also tried to call the `load()` function on the video element?

Answer (score 0):

As 'Bas Pauw' said *load()* is the key.

Just an example for Javascript without libraries:

```
Courtesy w3schools.
<button onclick="myFunction()" type="button">Change Video</button><br>

<video id="myVideo" controls>
  <source id="mp4_src" src="https://www.w3schools.com/tags/mov_bbb.mp4">
</video>

<script> 
function myFunction() { 
    document.getElementById("mp4_src").src = "https://www.w3schools.com/tags/movie.mp4";
    document.getElementById("myVideo").load();
} 
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should change the source with Video.js's API.

```
videojs('my-video').src({
  src: 'http://example.com/video.mp4',
  type: 'video/mp4'
});
```

Directly manipulating a source element won't work when the player is initialised. You need to use the `src()` API so that Video.js can load the right tech for the source, e.g. Html5 or YouTube.